# iOS Forward Geocoding returns shaky, sparse results

Tags: ios, uitableview, geocoding, clgeocoder

I'm working on an app that needs to be able to search for locations by name, and it seems like it should be fairly simple thanks to `CLGeocoder`.  I've got it all set up, and it seems to be working, but I'm getting an amazingly sparse results.

Whatever I type, I get at most 1-2 results, often none at all.  When I search for "Aquarium of the Pacific," it finds it correctly, but only when I actually finish typing it: leave off even just the last letter "c", and it's got nothing.  Typing in my own address returns nothing, even when I type it out fully.

Is that how this works?  Surely `CLGeocoder` isn't THAT useless?  Is there anything I can do to increase the number of returned results, or widen the range of possible matches?

Below is the code I'm working with, connected up to a simple `UITableView` and `UISearchBar` pair...

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    [_placeResults removeAllObjects];
    [_geocoder geocodeAddressString:searchText completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks) {
            [_placeResults addObject:aPlacemark];
        }
        [_mainTableView reloadData];
     }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_placeResults count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SearchTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    CLPlacemark *thisPlace = [_placeResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.labelTitle setText:[[[thisPlace addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] objectAtIndex:0]];

    return cell;
}
```

As I said, it DOES work *a little bit*, so I know everything is hooked up correctly.  It's just not working very *well*.

Any advice?

Comment: iOS doesn't really have an "location auto-complete search api".  CLGeocoder and MKLocalSearch assume that the complete text is provided.  A popular alternative is Google's Place Autocomplete API though technically you may need to also switch to using the Google Maps for iOS SDK since the Google Autocomplete results "must be used with a Google map" (if you're intending to show the results on a map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have got the wrong idea about the purpose of CLGeocoder. It is meant to convert between Geo Location Coordinates and it's full text title.

Moreover, did you read the documentation? CLGeocoder needs to contact the Geo Coding Servers. So calling it on each iteration of a `textDidChange:` message is not only an improper use, it's highly innefficient.

From Apple's Docs:

> Applications should be conscious of how they use geocoding. Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. (When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder returns an error object with the value kCLErrorNetwork to the associated completion handler.) Here are some rules of thumb for using this class effectively:
>
> Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action.
>
> If the user performs multiple actions that involve geocoding the same location, reuse the results from the initial geocoding request instead of starting individual requests for each action.

The idea here, is that each App is rate limited by Apple. So you need to use the API sparingly, and by submitting full text queries.

Excerpt for `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:`

> After initiating a forward-geocoding request, do not attempt to initiate another forward- or reverse-geocoding request.

Comment: I was going off of the "Converting Place Names Into Coordinates" section at the bottom of Apple's "Geocoding Location Data" documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html), which seems to indicate that this is a viable way to find locations based on written names/addresses.  But if this isn't the way to do it, I'm certainly open to a better idea.  How would you go about making a location search feature, like one might have in a Google/Apple Maps-style app?

Comment: @AlexanderWinn IF you are trying to do some kindof Autocomplete Location Based Search (i.e. the user starts to type and an address comes up) you would most likely need to implement your own database, as it is an expensive operation. 
Take a look at SOLR from Apache, they have the search functionality you are looking for. Warning though, this is not a simple task.

Comment: Arg, fair enough.  Well thanks for your help!  I was hoping there was a quick way to implement a live search for locations, but if not, I suppose the question has been answered.  Shucks.

Comment: +1 for Shucks. And yeah. If you ever do find a service, let me know... Though, I am sure it would be extremely expensive.